# Removing several strings from all filenames in a directory by a console operation

Tags: python, string, bash, file-rename

I'm wondering what is the easiest way to rename all files in a directory.

I have file names which look like those:

```
output_original_2018_0729_112557_065.JPG_7c82d91a-6a2a-4f9f-a9ed-ccbc34afe7a9.JPG
output_original_2018_0729_112557_065.JPG_15f07152-76d0-4834-993b-2ca8f589310f.JPG
output_original_2018_0729_112631_070.JPG_cd08da59-0de7-4a94-b769-5450fb80e982.JPG
```

Now i want to remove the leading and the ending parts and also rename the file itself with a counter (first, second, third) if the filename if the filename is the same. Which leads to a result like this:

```
2018_0729_112557_065_1.JPG
2018_0729_112557_065_2.JPG
2018_0729_112631_070.JPG
```

Thanks in advance

Edited: I tried regex to cut off the first part:

```
for file in *; do echo mv ./"$file" ./"$(echo "$file" | cut -c17-)";
```

Comment: Yes, i tried something like this for file in *; do echo mv ./"$file" ./"$(echo "$file" | cut -c17-)"; done to cut of the "output_original_" string at first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should produce the exact output you desired:

```
import os
import re
from collections import defaultdict


folder = "/path/to/out_original/folder"
regex = "output_original_(.+?.JPG)"

p = defaultdict(list)

for x in os.listdir(folder):
    try:
        p[re.findall(regex, x)[0]].append(x)
    except:
        pass

for k, v in p.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        os.rename(os.path.join(folder, v[0]), os.path.join(folder, k))
    else:
        count = 1
        for x in v:
            os.rename(
                os.path.join(folder, x), 
                os.path.join(folder, os.path.splitext(k)[0] + "_{}.JPG".format(count))
            )
            count += 1
```

Comment: This is amazing. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what was requested in terms of the counters, but I don't have time to fix it:

```
import re
import os

filenames = [
    'output_original_2018_0729_112557_065.JPG_7c82d91a-6a2a-4f9f-a9ed-ccbc34afe7a9.JPG',
    'output_original_2018_0729_112557_065.JPG_15f07152-76d0-4834-993b-2ca8f589310f.JPG',
    'output_original_2018_0729_112631_070.JPG_cd08da59-0de7-4a94-b769-5450fb80e982.JPG',
]

new_filenames = set()

for filename in filenames:
    base_filename = new_filename = re.match(
        r'output_original_(.+?)\.JPG',
        filename,
    ).group(1)
    count = 1
    while new_filename in new_filenames:
        new_filename = "{base_filename}_{count}".format(**locals())
        count += 1
    new_filenames.add(new_filename)
    new_filename += ".JPG"
    print(filename, '->', new_filename)
    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
```

Output:

```
output_original_2018_0729_112557_065.JPG_7c82d91a-6a2a-4f9f-a9ed-ccbc34afe7a9.JPG -> 2018_0729_112557_065.JPG
output_original_2018_0729_112557_065.JPG_15f07152-76d0-4834-993b-2ca8f589310f.JPG -> 2018_0729_112557_065_1.JPG
output_original_2018_0729_112631_070.JPG_cd08da59-0de7-4a94-b769-5450fb80e982.JPG -> 2018_0729_112631_070.JPG
```

Comment: just tried out:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rename_names.py", line 25, in <module>
    os.rename(filename, new_filename)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

You could use bash patter substitution and `mv --backup=t` to rename repeated file names:

```
find . -name "output_original*" | while read -r file; do
    origin=$file
    file=${file/\.\/output_original_/}
    file=${file/JPG*/JPG}
    mv --backup=t $origin $file
done
```

sample input:

```
find . -name "output*"
./output_original_2018_0729_112557_065.JPG_15f07152-76d0-4834-993b-2ca8f589310f.JPG
./output_original_2018_0729_112557_065.JPG_7c82d91a-6a2a-4f9f-a9ed-ccbc34afe7a9.JPG
./output_original_2018_0729_112631_070.JPG_cd08da59-0de7-4a94-b769-5450fb80e982.JPG
./output_original_2018_0729_112557_065.JPG_15f07152-76d0-4834-993b-2ca8f589310x.JPG
```

output:

```
$find . -name "2018*"
./2018_0729_112557_065.JPG
./2018_0729_112557_065.JPG.~1~
./2018_0729_112557_065.JPG.~2~
./2018_0729_112631_070.JPG
```

Comment: Nice idea, but this still does not have a counter in it, like the previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Expounding on @Sergio's idea:

```
# Make last also numbered
for file in *.JPG.~1~; do
  cp --backup=numbered $file ${file/.~1~}
  rm ${file/.~1~}
done
```

That will turn `2018_0729_112557_065.JPG` into `2018_0729_112557_065.JPG.~3~`.

Now, to change the numbering scheme:

```
for file in *.JPG.~*~; do
  new_name=$( echo "$file" | sed 's/\.JPG.~\([0-9]*\)~/_\1.JPG/'
  mv "$file" "$new_name"; done
done
```

Of couse, if you have things other that .JPG, you will need to modify this.